# Are intergalactic voids inertial frames?

Tags: universe, reference-frames

I know earth is a non-inertia frame, so is the solar system, the milky way, the local group and even our super cluster. But what about all the space, the void that is left outside of the superclusters.

From wikipedia "Interspersed among superclusters are large voids of space in which few galaxies exist. Superclusters are frequently subdivided into groups of clusters called galaxy clouds."

When we talk of the voids the only movement we can talk about is the space expansion, not even a real movement as I have learnt after several debates and discussions.

So are these voids actually inertial frames?

If they are not, why are they not?

Comment: Any freely-falling frame is inertial, and an accelerometer will read 0. For systems of finite size, this is only an approximation because of the non-uniformity of the gravitational field, which you can check by letting several bodies fall besides each other: In general, the distances between them will change, even in the absence of external/non-gravitational forces.

Comment: @Christoph: I am not asking about approximate inertial frames here.

Comment: approximate inertial systems are the only kind there are, and this is true for intergalactic voids in the same way as it's true for any other freely-falling systems; you cannot get rid of the non-uniform gravitational influence of the rest of the universe

Comment: @Christoph: Please explain the point I raised as a comment in flint72's answer

Comment: Also, earth is "approximately" in free fall, so why not set it as (locally) inertial system?

Comment: I think that the thing is, the void is not a frame at all. Otherwise, it could travel at arbitrary speed, which is nonsense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In special relativity the definition of an inertial frame is straightforward because acceleration is absolute, that is you can always tell if you're in an accelerated frame because you feel a force.

However this is not true in general relativity. Indeed, in GR every frame is locally inertial. For example, the international space station is accelerating towards the Earth (at about 8.8 m/sec$^2$) but as we know from the video footage the astronauts on board are weightless. If you painted over all the windows on the ISS the astronauts inside wouldn't be able to tell whether they were orbiting the Earth or at the centre of an intergalactic void.

Well, not quite.

The way you tell if you are in an inertial frame is to surround yourself with a sphere of test masses and watch them to see what happens. If you did this in the ISS then you'd find the sphere gradually became stretched into an ellipsoid due to the tidal forces from the Earth. The edge of the sphere nearest the earth orbits very slightly faster then the edge farthest from the Earth, so the sphere ends up being stretched. This effect gets bigger as you increase the size of your test sphere, so if you make the sphere big you'll see the effect quickly. But if you make the sphere small enough the changes will be smaller than your experimental errors and you won't be able to tell you're not in an inertial frame.

Now back to your question. There is nowhere in the universe that you are infinitely far from all masses, so everywhere in the universe there will some gravitational field to perturb your test masses. In other words there are no inertial frames anywhere! But the region over which your frame looks inertial, i.e. the region within which you can't detect any change in your test masses, will vary from place to place. It will be much, much bigger in an intergalactic void than in the ISS.

So to summarise:

1. there are no perfectly inertial frames **anywhere**
2. there are approximately inertial frames **everywhere**
3. the difference is the size of the approximately inertial region

Comment: so that also means that non-inertial frame does not mean non accelerated frame, but simply a frame where forces can be felt right?

Comment: In GR a non-inertial frame would be any frame in which objects at rest wrt the frame did not follow geodesics. But yes, in practice it means any frame in which a force can be felt.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question of your exact words "actual inertial frames", I would say no. There will always be some small gravitational effects, even far out in the vast nothingness of space, they would just be very small perhpas.

Comment: Well I wont even try to say I know much about frames,  but what is written on wikipedia says the frame needs to be accelerated to be non-inertial. Well earth and all have mass and an applied force would move them, accelerating them. But voids have no mass and even there are forces they would not accelerate! How can they be non-inertial then?

Comment: @rijul gupta : Well in the sense that the gravitational effects are infinite in range, so far as we know. So you cannot just pick a point in empty space and say that there are no forces, that is, that you are in an inertial frame. Rather, you need to be in gravitational free-fall for the frame to be inertial.$\\$ 
Unless this is what you meant by the void, in which case it would a tautology.

Comment: I did not for once say no forces, I just repeated that wikipedia says non-inertial frames are supposed to be accelerated. There may definitely be non-zero gravitational forces but since a void has no mass it would certainly not accelerate which by wikipedia's definition would mean an inertial frame.

Comment: @rijulgupta the principle of equivalence says that being in a frame where objects experience a gravitational force is equivalent to being in a nonintertial frame.

Comment: @NeuroFuzzy : can you give some source to confirm that and/or read further?